# Cannot get the path for a folder to work in linux

Tags: bash, ubuntu, path, amazon-web-services

I currently can not get my new path to work;

The instructions tell me to:

To add eb files to your path:
Linux/Mac OS X (Bash shell):
export PATH=$PATH:

The folder is located at:

```
/home/play/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.3.1/eb
```

Using these guides:

[ubuntu guide](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path) and [Junkie](http://blog.jseibert.com/post/491585200/setting-your-path-on-ubuntu-everywhere)

I added this to my .bashrc file:

```
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/play/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.3.1/eb/linux/python3:$PATH"
```

Then I ran :

```
play@ubuntu:~$ source .bashrc
play@ubuntu:~$ eb status
eb: command not found
```

Could you guys tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you re-read your `.bashrc` file?  Try `. ~/.bashrc`...this should set the path.  Personally, I hate the idea of more than doubling the length of the path — I'd drop the leading `$PATH` from the assignment, probably.

Comment: yes i read my .bashrc file with: source .bashrc

Comment: `source ~/.bashrc` is the same as `. ~/.bashrc`, so that should be OK.  Did you print `$PATH` before and after doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple things that could be the source of your problem:

1. You say the path to the EB CLI package is `/home/play/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.3.1/eb`, but you are using `$HOME/play/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.3.1/eb` in your example. From your prompt, I guess your username is `play`, so the most likely value of `$HOME` is `/home/play`. This means you are using `/home/play/play/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.3.1/eb`. Use either of these, but do not mix them:

   ```
   /home/play/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.3.1/eb
   $HOME/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.3.1/eb
   ```
2. You have duplicate members in your `PATH`, because your export statement contains `$PATH` twice. It should look like this instead:

   ```
   export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/play/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.3.1/eb/linux/python3"
   ```

This advice is based on [this Getting Started page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-reference-get-started.html).

Finally, this change in your `.bashrc` will only affect future shells. To apply it to your current shell, run `source ~/.bashrc`

Comment: I tried:
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/play/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.3.1/eb/linux/python2.7"
updated the .bashrc file, then ran source ~/.bashrc
nothing happened. :/

Comment: Got it: export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.3.1/eb/linux/python2.7" | Thanks just as u stated it, play was being duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

I wanna add a comment but it needs a full answer.

Replace this:

```
        export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/play/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.3.1/eb/linux/python3:$PATH"
```

By:

```
        export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/play/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.3.1/eb/linux/python3"
```

Another thing, maybe there is abin directory in this path /home/play/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.3.1/eb/linux/python3, so check it and add the following:

```
        export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/play/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.3.1/eb/linux/python3:$HOME/play/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.3.1/eb/linux/python3/bin"
```

Comment: None of such modifications made the trick.

Answer (score 0):

`$HOME` is going to be your home directory, something like `/home/yepUknow`. Change your `PATH` export to

```
export PATH="/home/play/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.3.1/:$PATH"
```

(dropping the leading copy of `$PATH`, as suggested by Jonathan Leffler). I've adjusted the directory a bit, but I may have taken too much off. Make sure the directory you add preceding the colon actually contains the program/script called `eb` that you are trying to call.

Comment: I tried:
export PATH="home/play/AWS-ElasticBeanstalk-CLI-2.3.1/eb/linux/python3:$PATH"
No results

Comment: You are missing the leading `/` for `/home/play/...`.